# How iOS widget to build systemMedium in simulator?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

My widget can support size like this:

```
.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall,.systemMedium])
```

but when I try to run in my simulator, it always build the small size and never build the other. Can anyone else tell me how to build the medium one in simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nerver mind, It can config in environment , just look https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/debugging-widgets